# Downgrade PDF version with Ghostscript 8.70: A pdfmark destination page 34 points beyond the last page 22

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, php

**Background**

- My requirement is a feature to watermark PDF docs on demand within a LAMP stack (PHP 7.3).
- The webapp has a collection of PDF docs loaded into a MySQL table. The docs originated as PDF files with various versions of PDF.
- My watermarking solution is based on [this article using FPDF](https://phppot.com/php/php-watermark-pdf/).
- I had the problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154190).
- So I added Ghostscript to the flow, to downgrade all docs to PDF 1.4.

**Ghostscript Command**

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/tmp/63d319f2d1018.pdf /tmp/63d319f2cfb51.pdf
```

**Error for one problem doc**

- For most docs, the flow is working and adding watermarks.
- However, one doc (so far) results in this error (sorry for the formatting):

> Error: /rangecheck in --makepattern-- Operand stack: --dict:11/20(L)-- --dict:14/23(L)-- --dict:14/23(L)-- --nostringval-- false --dict:14/15(L)-- --nostringval-- Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 24 1 34 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 1811 4 10 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1150/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:76/200(L)-- --dict:76/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:25/40(L)-- --dict:3/5(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2 GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 GPL Ghostscript 8.70: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 34 points beyond the last page 22.

Is there a better Ghostscript command? Or a better approach?

Comment: this appears to be unrelated to tex

Comment: Got it. I saw a Ghostscript question on Stack Overflow closed as "off topic." Where does my topic belong?

Comment: I suggest to subscribe to stackoverflow and post there or contact this user, who seems to be an expert in this subject matter: https://stackoverflow.com/users/359307/kurt-pfeifle

Comment: sounds as if the pdf is faulty so you probably need some tool that can correct such an error.